# ListIterator's previous() method

Tags: java, listiterator

Documentation says :

> previous()
>
> Returns the previous element in the list and moves the cursor position backwards.

Let's say I have an ArrayList :  [1,2,3,4,5]

Initially cursor points here :    [  1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ]

```
                      ^
                      |
```

And after this piece of code

```
ListIterator li = al.listIterator();
    while(li.hasNext()){
        int ab = (int) li.next();
        if(ab > 4)
            break;
    }
```

[  1   2  3  4  5  ]

```
       ^
       |
```

But when I do

```
System.out.println(li.previous());
```

It outputs `5` instead it should output `4` since it returns previous element. Why does this happen? How do I fix this?.

Comment: I think your question has some crucial formatting problems that make it impossible to understand your problem. Please fix the cursor pointer you have in the question.

Comment: the javadoc also states `Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly`. Since you called `next` beforehand it will print the same element again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause :**

Form [`docs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#next()) of [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#next()) method

> Returns the next element in the list and advances the cursor position. This method may be called repeatedly to iterate through the list, or intermixed with calls to previous() to go back and forth. (Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly.)

That's telling why you are getting 5 and not 4.

**Fix :**

As again said in docs, to get the desired output, what you can do is , when the condition met, move one step back.

```
ListIterator li = al.listIterator();
    while(li.hasNext()){
        int ab = (int) li.next();
        if (ab > 4){
            li.previous();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`li.next()` just returned `5` (because `5 > 4`)

Therefore, `li.previous()` returns `5` again.

(And an other call to `li.next()` would have thrown a `NoSuchElementException`)

Answer (score 1):

You are not correct as to where the index is located.

When first initialized, the pointer will be here:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
 ^
```

After your code, it will be pointing here:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
                     ^
```

So the previous value after your code is actually 5, as you saw when you tested.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your loop, `li.next()` returns `5` **and** moves past it forward. So, `previous()` returns `5` now. At this point, `hasNext()` is `false` anyways so the `break` within the `if` is not necessary since the loop condition evaluates to `false` automatically.